# Braintree alternative or any good embedded checkout?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payment, braintree, payment-processing

we are about to launch a service marketplace. We've implemented Braintree Payments, but when we were about to go to the production, they've declined our application (no reason specified).

Please, do you know some good alternatives? We certainly don't want to be responsible for holding the credit card information, so iframes for fields is a must. We also can't use Stripe (our country is not supported) and Bluesnap is most likely dead.

Thanks for any advice.

[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mble.png)

Answer (score 2):

I think that BlueSnap can provide a satisfying solution for you. Please visit: [BlueSnap](https://home.bluesnap.com/)

Goodluck!